# Call C# dll function from TypeScript | Overwolf

Tags: c#, typescript, dll

### What I want to do

I'm currently trying to call a C# dll with TypeScript using overwolf plugin.

### Problem

I want to load a dll and call a function, but an error occurs as undefined.

### What I did

I referred [this page](https://overwolf.github.io/topics/using-plugins/how-to-use-plugins-in-your-app).

I have built the below C# class library as a dll. And this file name is `ClassLibrary1.dll`.

```
namespace MyNameSpace {
  public class MyClass {
    public static bool isActive() {
      // some code......
    } 
  }
}
```

I created a `plugins` folder in the same directory as the `manifest.json` of the Typescript project and put `ClassLibrary1.dll` there.
And added the following to `manifest.json`.

```
"data": {
  "extra-objects": {
    "myPlugin": {
      "file": "plugins/ClassLibrary1.dll",
      "class": "MyNamespace.MyClass"
    }
  },
}
```

↑ (Is this way of defining "class" correct?)

And finally, the function is called when the button is pressed.

```
// on button pressed
button.addEventListener('click', () => {

  overwolf.extensions.current.getExtraObject("myPlugin", (result) => {
    // `result.success` is always true
    try{
      if (result.success) {
         result.object.isActive(); // undefined
      }else{
         // never called here
      }
    }catch(e){
    
    }
  });

});
```

---

Am I doing something wrong?
I used to write C# but I'm new to Typescript and Overwolf.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing `static` from C# code solved the issue.

Result:

```
namespace MyNameSpace {
  public class MyClass {
    public bool isActive() {
      // some code......
    } 
  }
}
```